# Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

Is there any way to get [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313) for Visual studio 2015 ? Or will it come later, what is the situation ?

<strike>**ETA**: New preview release of [SSDT October 2015 Preview in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx) now supports .rptproj extensions.</strike>

For the most recent version of SSDT you can find at [SQL Server Data Tools Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/)

**ETA**: [SQL Server Data Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=799659) are now GA (Generally available) as of 2016-06-01

Comment: What ! Closed for being OFF-TOPIC ! The problem is clear : There is no **report server project** in the default instalation of visual studio 2015

Answer (score 19, accepted):

New preview release of SSDT November 2015 Preview in Visual Studio now supports .rptproj extensions.

**ETA**: [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501) are now GA (Generally available) as of 2016-06-01

Comment: The link says `open Visual Studio 2015 and choose the Tools > Extensions and Updates menu. SQL Server tooling updates will appear in the Updates list.` -- I'm on Win 10 / VS 2015 and there is no "SQL Server tooling" update under the Update list

Comment: I needed to go to `3. Set up an Administrative Install Point (optional)` in that link - and download the SSDTSetup.exe and run it. (Didn't have to do any of the cmd line stuff etc. Just ran the SSDTSetup.exe)

Comment: @mmcrae if i recall correctly, it would appear in updates list if you have all the updates and KB of visual studio 2015. But still i installed it through external setup.

Comment: This MSDN page seems to keep an updated link to the latest build of SSDT for 2015: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx  The latest version as of writing is a Sept 26 2016 release no longer labeled as a "Preview".

Comment: @Arkaine55 removed link from answer as it is no longer valid. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The only information we have so far is from Matt Masson (Senior Program Manager
at Microsoft) that he shared at Ignite earlier this year "These features will be first available as out of box downloadable for SSDT-BI for Visual Studio 2013 and will be later released for SSIS 2016 (SSDT-BI for Visual Studio 2015)
" so it's coming but no information on when.

From his session BRK2578 at Ignite 2015.

Comment: I will accept answer if no one else answers with some way of accessing .rptproj in visual studio 2015 in next 24h

Comment: @IgorisAzanovas did you find a way to open rptproj files in Visual Studio 2015?  Mine still comes up with incompatible.  Thanks!

Comment: @GaryEwanPark No i haven't. For now i use Visual Studio 2013 and loading solution only with Reporting project.

Comment: @IgorisAzanovas thanks for getting back to me.  I will use this approach for now as well.  Hopefully there will be an update to the tooling soon to support this project type.

Answer (score 9):

SSIS support is now in preview as part of a single SSDT (database + BI) installer. See this blog post for full information: [SQL Server Data Tools Preview update for August 2015](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2015/09/01/sql-server-data-tools-preview-update-for-august-2015.aspx). The following information from that post may be relevant to you:

> SQL Server Database tooling is always installed since it is part of the core Visual Studio experience. For now SSIS tools is the only additional option available, with SSAS and SSRS coming soon.
>
> **SQL Server version support across the tools**
>
> Database tools will continue to support SQL Server 2005 through to SQL
>   Server 2016, including Azure SQL DB. The Business Intelligence
>   projects continue to have a different support matrix. Please note that
>   during the Preview period support for versions of SQL Server earlier
>   than SQL Server 2016 may be limited. In the SQL Server 2016 RTM
>   time-frame support for earlier SQL Server versions will be improved.

Disclosure: I work on the SSDT (database) team.

Comment: should this preview be able to open rptproj files?  I have just installed it, and tried to open a solution which contains one of these projects, and it gets marked as incompatible.  Thanks!

Comment: @GaryEwanPark - no, as mentioned Integration Services projects are supported in this version. RS (rptproj) will be coming soon so expect within the next few months. You will see the checkboxes during installation for the different services types (IS, RS, AS) which is a good way of telling when support for them will arrive.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me.  Now that I have the preview of the tooling installed, will I be prompted within Visual Studio when there are updates available, or will I need to keep an eye out elsewhere for updates getting released?

Comment: For right now we do not have auto-update for the Preview tools enabled. We'll work on that for future updates, but you can track release announcements on the SSDT blog - blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/

Answer (score 3):

You can find it at
[SSDT July 2015 RTM for Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)

> SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) is a modern database development tool for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database. As a database developer, you can design, develop, build, test and publish a database with the same ease as you would develop an application in Visual Studio

Comment: That would normally be seen as a link only answer, but it still *is* the answer to the question, now that it's out.

Comment: @JohnMark I don't get it how it helps me with reporting services .rptproj extensions ?

Comment: No, even the latest SSDT Sept 2015 Preview does not support opening .rptproj. And it supposes to have SSDT-BI as a unified installer since August preview

Answer (score 3):

April 2016 preview update available:

**Download**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

**Blog Post**
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/04/15/sql-server-data-tools-preview-update-for-april-2016/

Answer (score 0):

March 2016 Preview (v14.0.60316.0) available

Download and blog post [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt429383)

If you're using SQL Server 2016 RC2 then use the version [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/04/05/ssdt-preview-update-rc2/)