# SSRS in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I am in the process of upgrading from Visual Studio 2010 to VS 2015 and can't find the Business Intelligence tools in VS2015.  We have the Enterprise Version.  Can someone point me in the correct direction?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: It might not be available yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671571/business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2015

Answer (score 0):

What were the Business Intelligence Development Suite (BIDS) is now known as SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT).  I realise this is an old question, but [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx) advises that

> Since SQL Server tooling is included in VS, the updates will be pushed
>   through VS Update and users will be prompted when VS is open. If you'd
>   like to check for updates manually, open Visual Studio 2015 and choose
>   the Tools > Extensions and Updates menu. SQL Server tooling updates
>   will appear in the Updates list.

Comment: `SQL Server tooling updates will appear in the Updates list` - and what if this is not the case i.e. it doesn't appear there?

Comment: If it's not in the list, then you may be able to find a `SSDTSetup.exe` file that will manually install the updates on your PC. Usually the update is for a specific version of VS

Answer (score 0):

Here's the SSDT Team Blog post announcing (and linking) to the latest version following the GA of SQL Server 2016. Supposedly, this package makes VS2015 compatible with SQL Server 2016 and ALL previous versions and combines the SSDT (Data Dude) capabilities for database design and management with SSDT-BI (BIDS) features for SSIS, SSAS (MD/Tabular) and SSRS.

[Link to SSDT Team Blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2016/06/01/sql-server-data-tools-ga-update-for-june-2016/)