# How do I open SSRS (.rptproj) and SSIS (.dtproj) files in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, visual-studio-2015

How Can I open this kind of project in the last version of VS21015.

I get the error: 
This project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual Studio.

Supposedly, It was included the SSDT in this version.

Comment: Doesn't work yet. Currently, you need VS 2012 to work with SSRS/SSIS for SQL Server 2012, VS 2013 for SQL Server 2014

Comment: @billinkc - I agree on the fact that this question is a duplicate, but a link to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671571/business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2015) is more appropriate IMHO.

Comment: @SébastienSevrin Thanks for the link, I hadn't seen that question roll through. My intention once SQL Server 2016 is released is to update the duplicate with information concerning VS 2015. It'll be an interesting time because MS indicated as part of this release they are coming up with a unified developer tool where you can target a specific release, so in theory, VS 2015 can output SSIS for SQL Server 2016 or 2014. How that will *actually* work, versions supported, etc very much remains to be seen.

Comment: Finally the [SSDT December 2015 Preview for Visual Studio 2015] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/mt186501) now supports my specific question regarding open SSRS and SSIS projects.

Comment: Ok,  so if this is a DUPLICATE question, then why does the other question pertain to VS 2012/2013  , especially right in the Title?    You cannot lump IDE of different versions together,  OMG.   Imagine the rest of the world industries did this?   Toyota Camry 2013 and 2014 ,  what if those cars have a re-designed engine for example ?